# deleting an element from array list where each element is an array itself

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have created a list of arrays in java using the following command.

```
List<String[]> rowList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

I am storing elements into it using the following command

```
rowList.add(new String[] { IP, port}); where IP and port are strings.
```

but when I try to delete an entry from the list using the below command, it does not work.

```
rowList.remove(new String[] {IP , port});
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It's because those two arrays are different objects. Create a custom class that manages those `String[]` arrays and implement your own `equals(Object o)` and `hashCode()` methods.

Comment: I got the following from the manual of array list in java.     
boolean java.util.List.remove(Object o) :
Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list, if it is present .

Comment: Just as @QBrute said, [`remove`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#439) uses to `.eqauls()` to check equality.

Comment: just to delete use index number

Comment: i cannot use index number to delete.

Comment: You can use the [removeIf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method: `rowList.removeIf(row -> Arrays.equals(row, new String[] {IP , port}));`